# Complex Hyperbolic space and $U(1,n)$

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Consider the projective model of $HP^{n}$ it is an open subset of the projective space, as an open subset we can restrict the FS form of $\mathbb{C}P^{n}$, given by the hermitian inner product of signature $(1,n)$ in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$.

What I want to prove is that this form restricted to the hyperbolic is invariant under the action of $U(1,n)$.

I read on Epstein's Analytical and Geometric aspects of hyperbolic space that the tangent space of a point in the hyperbolic is isomorphic to the ortogonal space of that point, considering any lift. Is this because you can see the projective space as a quotient of the unit sphere? 
I was thinking to use this representation to try proving the invariance.

Or if anyone knows another path it would be more that welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This should just be a simple calculation in multivariable calculus. The calculation takes place entirely in the indefinite inner product space, *not* in the projective space.

Let me state what happens in the real hyperbolic setting as opposed to the complex hyperbolic setting. The only differences arise in calculus and linear algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ rather than over $\mathbb{R}$, but the notation is simpler over $\mathbb{R}$.

Consider $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ with coordinates $x_1,...,x_{n+1}$, and use the bilinear pairing 
$$x \cdot y = x_1 y_1 - x_2 y_2 - ... - x_{n+1} y_{n+1}
$$ 
with associated indefinite norm of signature $(1,n)$ given by 
$$|x|^2 = |x_1|^2 - |x_2|^2 - ... - |x_{n+1}|^2
$$ 
We are considering one sheet of the two-sheeted hyperboloid, namely 
$$\mathbb{RH}^n = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \mid |x|^2=1, \, x_1 > 0\}
$$ 
Given $p \in \mathbb{RH}^n$, the fact that the tangent space of $\mathbb{RH}^n$ at $p$ is the orthogonal subspace at $p$ should be a simple multivariable calculus problem. By definition $\mathbb{RH}^n$ is a level set of $|x|^2$ passing through $p$. And a simple calculation shows that the tangent space of that level set at $p$ is equal (up to a constant factor of $2$) to the orthogonal subspace of the vector $p$, where "orthogonality" is determined using the indefinite inner product.

The courage to believe this comes from the fact that it's all obvious using the standard Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, using the unit sphere $S^n$ as a level set of the norm: at a point $p \in S^n$, a calculation shows that $p$ equals the gradient of the norm at $p$ (up to a factor of $2$); and the tangent space of $S^n$ at $p$ equals the orthogonal subspace of the gradient vector.